# How to send binary data through sockets securely and make sure no-one can resend it?

Tags: php, vb.net, sockets, security, tcp

First of all, I am going to stat what I am building so if someone has an alternate solution for my problem.

Soo, Basically there is a game that has multiplayer option.

And I own a server.. However, There is a problem that people add illegal mods to there game to be able to gain unfair opportunities in the server.

So my idea was to create a custom launcher for the game that basically first of all check if the game is modded and if not, It sends a TCP request to the server that the player called `BLA` with the IP `xx.xx.xx` doesn't have any mods and is going to join now.

And also btw the connection is secured with AES128 encryption.

---

And now to my actual problem.

Soo.. While I was creating the encryption/decryption system. (Its a mix of AES and base64), I noticed that people could sniff the sockets and then copy the hash that was sent from the launcher to the server and then use any socket client app to simply send that hash AS IS without modifications..

The server will then simply think that the launcher sent it and actually believe it and then allow that player :/

So what I am asking for, Is there any way to workaround this ?
Like for example creating a way so that hashes are only use-able once.

Thanks in advanced for any help provided, greatly appreciated.
And also alternate solutions other then sockets are accepted :)

Comment: sure, just keep track of the hashes sent out, and when it "comes back", mark it as "used".

Comment: Why not just go with an established protocol like SSH for the socket connection?

Comment: I was thinking about that but the  problem is that coincidences can happen and someday the same hash is generated so i am pretty sure there is another better way instead of sockets.. So yeah keeping this my last solution.

Comment: And Jonathan, what do you mean with shh ?.. You mean ssl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here to discuss, such as how to make the encrypted communication non-replayable, and ultimately a disheartening reveal about how even fixing the issue will not actually make the system secure.

To fix the replayability of the encrypted communication you can either use a protocol which protects against this already (e.g. SSH), or roll your own solution and have your server send a large random number to the client, which then includes this number in the encrypted payload that includes the hash.  The server can then easily verify if the returned number matches the number it generated to ensure that the overall payload has not been replayed.

The problem here, however, is the same problem that plagues all DRM solutions that run on the clients computer, which is that your code can be compromised and debugged.  There is nothing to stop an attacker from simply debugging your code and finding your encryption key, thus being able to craft their own messages to say their client is valid.

This is obviously harder than a simple replay attack, but it is not only possible, it is probable, if your game / server is in any way popular.  Much more sophisticated client side security models have been broken, and ultimately there is no real way to make them impossible, merely more difficult (excepting perhaps some dedicated hardware solutions).

The only real solution is to ensure server side that clients cannot have an advantage.  This means that all client actions are verified server side and client knowledge is limited to only the information they should have.  Unfortunately this is not always possible to do perfectly, which is why wall hacks and other cheats still exist for the most popular games.

Comment: I can't use SSH because its unsupported in PAWN _The scripting lang.. for the server_ and there is no such plugin.

So I will use my own way, Thanks for pointing out to me how its done :)
When someone connects to the socket, A random IV will be sent encrypted to the client and then the client will decrypt then use that IV for the hash.. Now it will be almost imposible to be _simulated_ since they don't have the key to create _new_ hashes or decrypt the IV :).